# share core data between many users on app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I wanna develop an iOS app as the platform for many users. Is it possible to enable multiple users of my app to share resources on the same core data database?

Answer (score 0):

yes This can be done using a `custom url scheme` on the iphone by help of `iCloud URL`.
but it has some dark sides.If you use a custom url scheme, only one application "owns" the data. The other application would have to import data from the main application.

another method is `system pasteboard` i.e. clipboard.  you can put stuff on it and then launch another application with a URL that tells the other app to check the pasteboard.There's also the system pasteboard .

for more information on custom URL scheme [check this link](http://mobileorchard.com/lite-to-paid-iphone-application-data-migrations-with-custom-url-handlers/)

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative to iCloud (with the whole ownership issue) is to have an online server that stores the data remotely.

Then you can create a web service to store and retrieve the data from the server onto the device.